# How can I make HSQLDB a windows service?

Tags: java, windows, hsqldb

As per the subject, I know how to run HSQLDB from command line as well as from my code, but I need help with making HSQLDB a windows service.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try http://runasservice.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

And another solution

http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

I have found these two tutorials :

- [Install HSQL as a service using tomcat.exe](http://www.waldhor.com/hsql.htm)
- [Install HSQL as a service using Java Wrapper](http://www.jackbe.com/enterprise-mashup/blog/installing-presto-windows-services)